# Java won't match .*

Tags: java, regex

I have the following line in a file

```
00241386002|5296060|0|1|ClaimNote|29DEC2005:10:20:13.557194|JAR007|
```

I'm trying to match with

```
line.matches("^\d+\|\d+\|\d+\|\d+.+$")
```

That pattern works on the previous ~10k or so lines in the file.  It also works on the immediately preceding line which is the same up through the timestamp.  It does not, however, work on that line.  Even

```
line.matches(".*")
```

returns false.

Any help would be appreciated.

edits:

- the lines are created by buffered reader, so `\r` and `\n` will be trimmed.
- already tried clean and build, no dice.

answer:

- thanks to Pshemo with the answer in the first comment.  (?d).* (unix mode) also works.  there was a '\u0085' at the end of the line that the buffered reader didn't trim but Pattern considered a line terminator.

Comment: `.` represents any character except line separators. Is it possible that `line` contains `\n` or `\r`? What is result for `line.matches("(?s).*")`? If you are interested `(?s)` represents `DOTALL` flag which lets `.` match also line separators.

Comment: its true on mine. try clean and build

Comment: Can you try: `line.matches("[\\S\\s]*")`

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem: `"00241386002|5296060|0|1|ClaimNote|29DEC2005:10:20:13.557194|JAR007|".matches(".*")` returns `true` to me. Also honestly I can't think of any data which would return `false` for `matches("(s?).*")`. Consider posting code which we could use to easily reproduce your problem. Without it I am not sure how to help you.

Comment: My money is on whitespace just before the line in question. Perhaps a BOM.

Comment: If you're reading lines with BufferedReader, how did you get a line with CR and/or LF characters in it?

Comment: You can post the answer to your own question.

Comment: The presence of '\u0085' suggests that the file is in the "windows-1252" charset (or another Windows charset that uses the 128-159 codepoints), but your BufferedReader was constructed around a FileReader or InputStreamReader with no charset (or an incorrect charset).  Specify "windows-1252" as a charset and your regex will not need to change.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question due to typographical error, since it looks like neither @Pshemo or Kevin are interested in posting an answer.

Comment: OP [posted his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25631789/1393766) earlier but for some reasons decided to delete it and move it at the end of question (that is reasonable on some forums but not on Stack Overflow which OP may not know then). Anyway I posted my answer which should explain problem.

Answer (score 5):

### Problem

`\d+\|\d+\|\d+\|\d+` part of your regex seems to be working fine which suggests that problem must be related to `.*` part.

Lets test which characters can't by default by matched by `.` which could prevent `matches` from returning `true`.
(I will test only characters in range `0`-`FFFF` but Unicode have more characters - like surrogate pairs - so *I am not saying that these are only characters which `.` can't match* - even if it is today we can't be sure about the future).

```
for (int ch = 0; ch < '\uFFFF'; ch++) {
    if (!Character.toString((char)ch).matches(".*")) {
        System.out.format("%-4d hex: \\u%04x %n", ch, ch);
    }
}
```

We will get as result (added some comments and links)

[`10   hex: \u000a`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/000a/index.htm)   - line feed (\n)
[`13   hex: \u000d`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/000d/index.htm)   - carriage return (\r)
[`133  hex: \u0085`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0085/index.htm)   - next line (NEL)
[`8232 hex: \u2028`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2028/index.htm)   - line separator
[`8233 hex: \u2029`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2029/index.htm)   - paragraph separator

So I suspect that your string contains one of these characters. Now, not all tools properly recognize these characters as proper line separators (which regex recognizes). For instance, lets test `BufferedReader`

```
String data = "AAA\nBBB\rCCC\u0085DDD\u2028EEE\u2029FFF";

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(data));
String line = null;
while((line = br.readLine())!=null){
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

we are getting as result:

```
AAA
BBB
CCCDDD     EEE     FFF
   ⬑ here we have `\u0085` (NEL)
```

As you see tools which are not based on regex engine can return string which will represent single line, but still will contain characters which regex sees as line separators.

### Possible solutions

We can try to let `.` match any characters. To do so we can use `Pattern.DOTALL` flag (we can enable it also by adding `(?s)` in regex like `(?s).*`).

Also as you [already mention your question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/25631550/5), we can set regex engine in `Pattern.UNIX_LINES` mode (`(?d)` flag), which will make it see only `\n` as *line separator* (other characters like `\r` will not be treated as line separators).